# Marantz PMD660 stuck on loading

Tags: recording, equipment

My trusted Marantz PMD660 Solid state recorder recently developed a fault during a field trip in which it gets stuck on "Loading" when turned on with a CF Card inside. It starts fine without the card in and every functionality seems to be working fine in that case (I can change settings etc). However, I can't get past the "Loading" screen with the card in and therefore cannot record with it. I have tried a number of CF cards, formatted anew etc. I have not been able to find any information on the internet but I wondered if anyone has encountered the problem in the community and was able to overcome it.

Any suggestions/recommendations in this case?
Best regards
Caglar

Comment: Hello! Welcome to Bioacoustics Stack Exchange... Apologies that I do not have an answer for you, but as Marantz is well known (respected, I hope?) , I suspect you may get good assistance from their customer service. I would recommend this in addition to searching here-- If you DO get help to address the problem, please answer your own question here to help future scientists! (Also, accept your own answer if it solved the problem!). If they were not helpful, you can add a comment to that effect. Good luck!